# pandas read_csv will occasionally hang without an error message

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am encountering a strange error that occurs once every few days.  I have several virtual machines running on Google Cloud running a Python script.  The Python file is very large, but the part that gets stuck is the following:

```
try:
    f = urlopen('https://resources.lendingclub.com/SecondaryMarketAllNotes.csv')
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
except:
    print('error')
```

The first line of code always works, but the second line will occasionally stop the program.  What I mean by that is that the program will not continue execution, but it does not throw any kind of error.  I have logger running in my code in debug mode and it does not record anything.

Again, this happens very rarely, but when it does happen my virtual machines will stop.  When I look at the processes in `top`, I see Python running with 0% CPU, and there is still plenty of system memory available.  It will continue to sit there for hours without moving on to the next line of code or returning an error.

My application is very time sensitive and using urlopen is faster than using `pd.read_csv` to directly open the file.

I notice that when this rare error occurs, it happens at the same time in all of my virtual machines which means that there is likely something about the file being downloaded that is triggering this issue.  Why it doesn't cause an error is beyond me.

I would greatly appreciate any ideas on what might be causing this and what workarounds might be available.

I am using Python 3.5.3 and pandas 0.19.2

Comment: you're not really reading the link till the second line. how big is the file?

Comment: approximately 70-80MB

Comment: Downloading from an internet source takes a while. Try saving it to a local csv and reading from it

Comment: My application is very time sensitive.  The csv needs to be read as fast as possible, every millisecond counts.  Saving it to a local drive would drastically slow things down

Comment: I created a workaround using signal.alarm() to give the code a limited time to execute.  Not elegant but it is solved for now