# Python Pandas hanging in Docker container for small volume of data

Tags: python, pandas, docker

I am trying load the data worth of 44 mb in to a Pandas data frame. this is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import cx_Oracle
import sqlalchemy

engineor = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://xxxxx:xxx@xxx:1521/?service_name=XXX')
sql = "select * from accounts where date >= '10-MAY-18 06.00.16.170000000 PM'"
do = pd.read_sql(sql, engineor)
do.info(memory_usage='deep')
```

The above query returns around 70k rows and the size is around 44 mb.

When I run this from my local machine (Win 7) in Anaconda, the data loads in to data frame without any issues in a minute or two. However, when I run the same thing in Docker container (Linux based) it just hangs.

I verified that docker container has sufficient memory, and memory doesn't grow over time (although the size is quite small ~44 mb). It just gets submitted and hangs indefinitely that I am unable to kill it by pressing control + c or control + z. I need to disconnect from the machine and login back.

I tried to match the version of Pandas from Anaconda that I am running on local machine. But it didn't help much, it is still hanging. The only thing that is now differing between my local machine and the Python version. In docker container it is 3.5.3 and in my local version it is 3.6.3, and that Anaconda is running from Windows and docker container is Linux based. I am not sure if these things make any difference.

Any suggestions on how to overcome this?

Comment: I suspect your container is unable to access the Oracle database. You could try getting the logs for the container (identify the container ID using `docker [ps|container] ls` and then `docker logs [ID]`. If your container image includes a shell, you could try accessing the shell and pinging the DB: `docker exec --interactive --tty [ID] bash` (if not `bash` try `sh` and `ash`). I suspect, because you're using a Windows host that you're having to run Docker on a VM and thus the host networking (and your DNS names) aren't being extended to your container.

Comment: I can confirm that there are no such issues. It is able to load the data without any issues if the volume is small (100s or up to few thousands) consistently. It runs in to this issue when the volume happens to be big. Another inconsistent behavior is that.. when I tried to load 30k rows, it works sometimes, and it hangs most of the times.

Comment: Are you running Docker in a VM on a Windows machine? It's possible that resources are being constrained by the VM and/or there are networking problems with that configuration. I'm unfamiliar with Docker on Windows. Were you able to see anything in the logs?

Comment: It is on a Linux machine,and it is not a VM. The Python log is just stuck in step one without any updates. I tried running the above code in command line mode too because logs were not helpful, but as I mentioned earlier, it just hangs up without being able to come out using Control C or Control Z. It is more or less similar to this issue (except my is read_sql).. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48430886/pandas-read-csv-will-occasionally-hang-without-an-error-message .. I am not sure how to incorporate the workaround that he has suggested.

Comment: Unsure. You *may* want to try chunking the reads (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html).

Comment: Thanks.. I have tried chunking too. It didn't help. I tried setting even 100 rows it didn't work when the overall rows to deal with is big. I believe despite chunking, Pandas does bring the full data in to some form of OS memory, and start loading in to data frames as chunks, so it effectively ends up dealing with full volume, just that gets hidden syntactically.

Comment: I ran chunks in command line and noticed that it gets hung after reading particular number of rows. It varies from table to table.. it reads 9500 rows for table A, and 135k rows before hanging.. guess depends upon the volume each table is bringing. I am not sure why it gets stuck OS has enough memory. It stops at a particular memory usage.. (~500 mb) every time (up to 8 GB available).. cleaning up memory with del, gc.collect and empty data frame doesn't help much. Any way to have the Python Pands request more memory from OS? Or any way to clean memory within a for loop with chunks?

Comment: I don't know Pandas well enough to help. Hopefully someone else here has the answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into same problem as yours. I think **it's because of using socket communication inside bridge network container**.

Docker uses bridge network as default, just appointed ports could be forwarded to the host. This usually works when you use container as server. But **when your container runs as a client which creates sockets for communicating, there will be a problem**.

**The client needs to open up random ports to the server and bind them with sockets**. Because only selected ports could be forwarded, those random ports could not be found outside. Receiving data will never find the client container, and the sockets inside container will be left hang forever.

My solution is to **run containers using host network**. You could run container using command like

```
docker run --rm -d --network host --name my_nginx nginx
```

or using docker-compose

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  my_nginx:
    ...
    network_mode: "host"
```

But **beware using host network could cause port conflicts.**

PS. Although using host network solved my problem, I'm not an expert on socket or networking. Please correct me if i'm wrong about the mechnisims. I read socket in this article: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/definition.html.